# How to display the variable in a tkinter window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, g-code

I am completely new to Python and I am working on a following code that I made with big help of fellow stackflow user.

After running the script a tkinter window open where you can select a gcode file (it is a file with many many lines of instructions for a 3D printer) and later a specific value from this file is found.

What I would like to achieve is to:

1) Display this value under the load GCODE button in a tkinter window with a description/label.

2) Make some calculations on this value and display them in the tkinter window too.

3) Finaly make an executable of this script so everyone can use it, even without Python installed.

I am not sure if this is super easy or it's a lot of work as I am completely new to Python (and not so good in programming overall). I hope I have explained things good enough and thank you in advance for any input!

Gcode file for code testing: [GCODE FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jadu94v9fji4fhb/holder.gcode?dl=0)

Finaly the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import re
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

# Here, we are creating our class, Window, and inheriting from the Frame
# class. Frame is a class from the tkinter module. (see Lib/tkinter/__init__)
class Window(Frame):

    # Define settings upon initialization. Here you can specify
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class. 
        Frame.__init__(self, master)   

        #reference to the master widget, which is the tk window                 
        self.master = master

        #with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        self.init_window()

    # Load the gcode file in and extract the filament value
    def get_filament_value(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f_gcode:
            data = f_gcode.read()
            re_value = re.search('filament used = .*? \(([0-9.]+)', data)

            if re_value:
                value = float(re_value.group(1))
                return('Volume of the print is {} cm3'.format(value))
            else:
                value = 0.0
                return('Filament volume was not found in {}'.format(fileName))
        return value

    def read_gcode(self):
        root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("GCODE files", "*.gcode"), ("All files", "*.*")))
        self.value.set = self.get_filament_value(root.fileName)
#       self.value.set('Button pressed')

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def about_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("About", "Small software created by Bartosz Domagalski to find used filament parameters from Sli3er generated GCODE")

    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):

        # changing the title of our master widget      
        self.master.title("Filament Data")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a menu instance
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # create the file object)
        file = Menu(menu)
        help = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        help.add_command(label="About", command=self.about_popup)

        #added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)


        #Creating the labels
        self.value = StringVar()
        l_instruction = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=TOP, text="Load GCODE file to find volume, \n weight and price of used filament.")
        l = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.value)
#       l.place(x=85, y=45)
        l_instruction.pack()
        l.pack()

        #Creating the button
        gcodeButton = Button(self, text="Load GCODE", command=self.read_gcode)
        gcodeButton.pack()
#       gcodeButton.place(x=140, y=10)

        #status Bar
        status = Label(self, text="Waiting for file...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# root window created. Here, that would be the only window, but you can later have windows within windows.
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False,height=False);
root.geometry("220x300")


#creation of an instance
app = Window(root)

#mainloop 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `Label(s)` inside the same `Frame` as you have the button. And when I copied in your code I had to import the `filedalog` module as well (`from tkinter import filedalog`), the asterisk import didn't seem to cover it.

You could use a `StringVar()` variable (from tkinter) and assign it to the label. This variable you can `.set()` and `.get()` values from. Create variable and assign it to Label:

```
self.value = StringVar('', value="  Load GCODE file to find volume, \n weight and price of used filament.")
l = Label(self, textvariable=self.value)
```

Alter variable value:

```
self.value.set(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))
```

The Label you will have to place as you want it, just like you did with the Button with `quitButton.place`. There are other ways to handle the layout, grid and pack. But as far as I know, it is recommended to pick one layout style for all elements.

Creating an executable, "freezing" your code, is a broader topic. Take a [look here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/) for some options that you can look more into.

---

*edit:*

Updated working code. Changing the placement of widgets you'll figure out ;) Not looked at any new elements in your code.

```
from tkinter import *
import re
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog


# Here, we are creating our class, Window, and inheriting from the Frame
# class. Frame is a class from the tkinter module. (see Lib/tkinter/__init__)
class Window(Frame):
    # Define settings upon initialization. Here you can specify
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class.
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # reference to the master widget, which is the tk window
        self.master = master

        # with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        self.init_window()

    # Load the gcode file in and extract the filament value
    def get_filament_value(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f_gcode:
            data = f_gcode.read()
            re_value = re.search('filament used = .*? \(([0-9.]+)', data)

            if re_value:
                value = float(re_value.group(1))
                return 'Volume of the print is {} cm3'.format(value)
            else:
                return 'Filament volume was not found in {}'.format(fileName)

    def read_gcode(self):
        root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("GCODE files", "*.gcode"), ("All files", "*.*")))
        self.value.set(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def about_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("About",
                            "Small software created by Bartosz Domagalski to find used filament parameters from Sli3er generated GCODE")

    # Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):

        # changing the title of our master widget
        self.master.title("Filament Data")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a menu instance
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # create the file object)
        file = Menu(menu)
        help = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        help.add_command(label="About", command=self.about_popup)

        # added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)

        # Creating the labels
        self.value = StringVar()
        l_instruction = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=TOP,
                              text="  Load GCODE file to find volume, \n weight and price of used filament.")
        l = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.value)
        #       l.place(x=85, y=45)
        l_instruction.pack()
        l.pack()

        l_instruction.pack()
        self.value = StringVar()
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.value)
        l.pack()

        # Creating the button
        gcodeButton = Button(self, text="Load GCODE", command=self.read_gcode)
        gcodeButton.pack()
        #       gcodeButton.place(x=140, y=10)

        # status Bar
        status = Label(self, text="Waiting for file...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)


# root window created. Here, that would be the only window, but you can later have windows within windows.
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False);
# root.geometry("400x300")


# creation of an instance
app = Window(root)

# mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I tried to implement it as you suggest but with no good results (I have updated the code in the main question). I am slo not sure about this `filedalog` module as when I compile I have no prompts about it. Thank you also for the link I will look at it after the code is ready.

Comment: I noticed I had a typo on the label, used root as parent instead of self. Fixed that. Also added how it looks when put inside your code.

Comment: Ok I am slowly getting to understand this. So your example with hard coded "button pressed" message works. But still I can't display my value found from the gcode file. On top of that I realised that this way the new message ("button pressed" in your example) shows on top of the label and that label disappears. What I wanted to achieve is that after the gcode is loaded in value is shown in the tkinter window below the button and not instead of the label. I hope my explaining is clear enough ;)

Comment: I have updated the code to the newest version also you can download gcode file for test. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: To clarify even more, when you use the button and upload the gcode file in the shell you get back following message: `Volume of the print is 19.5 cm3` and I would like for this message to show up in the tkinter window as a new element below the upload GCODE button.

Comment: You will need to add another `Label`, and give it a `StringVar` as `textvariable`. And as mentioned, to alter the value of a `StringVar` you must use `.set()` as in the hardcoded `'Button Pressed'` example. And to return that message, you actually have to `return` it from your function instead of just the value.

Comment: And if you don't want the existing `Label` to change its text, you don't need that one to have a StringVar.

Comment: Now after the last changes I am getting follwing error`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = Window(root)
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.init_window()
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 77, in init_window
    l = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.value)
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'value'`. Thanks for the patience ;)

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined `self.value` before using it as `textvariable=self.value`.

Comment: But isn't it defined in `   def get_filament_value(self, fileName)` or I have to redefine it in the label too?

Comment: You need to define/create it before using it, the first time you use it is when assigning it to the `Label`. Setting the variable is not the same as defining/creating it. `self.value = StringVar()` is creating a `StringVar()` called `self.value`. You can then later set a value to it with  `self.value.set('Some string value')`.

Comment: Ok, my bad this error was due to the fact that I wrote Value with capital later instead lower case. Anyhow still the filament volume value that I am looking for is not displayed in the tkinter window, I have again uploaded the final version of the code.

Comment: The value you want to set must be in parentheses, not after `=`. Check it out in the long code I updated earlier ;)

Comment: Yes, omg, stupid mistake but I was writing by my self instead of copying and didn't notice this change. Thank you so much, now it is working as desired, almost ;) I might still bother you about other values though but I hope to solve it on my own.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out, sometimes it can be helpful to just write a small part of the code by itself. Instead of trying to implement something new directly. And when you understand how it works, it is easier to insert into the existing code project. Good luck :)

Comment: That is a good tip, otherwise to many things can go wrong, again thanks for your help! :D